# Script trigger timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script which triggers various fades / menu displays within a HTML5 App on scroll - the script is triggered via IScroll's scroll height as follows -

```
onScrollMove: function() {
           var thisScrol =  myScroll.getScrollY()

           if (thisScrol < -70 ){
                bgfadeToggle('on');
                notifToggle('on');

            }
            if (thisScrol > -70){
                bgfadeToggle('off');
                notifToggle('off');

            }



},
```

For reference the functions are as follows -

```
 function notifToggle(whichOne){

if (whichOne == "on" && fifth == "yes"){

    setTimeout(function() {fifth="no";}, 10)
        $('.notificationArea .notif').animate({

                    opacity: 0
                  }, 1500);

}
if (whichOne == "off" && fifth == "no"){

    setTimeout(function() {fifth="yes";}, 10)
        $('.notificationArea .notif').animate({

                    opacity:1
                  }, 2500);


}

}


//Move footer ul depending on scroll position
function bgfadeToggle(which){
if (which == "on" && first == "yes"){

    setTimeout(function() {first="no";$('#wrapper').addClass('hov');  }, 10)

                $('.appearLate').fadeIn('1000');

                $('.footer ul ').animate({
                    bottom: [ "-40", "linear" ],
                    opacity: "0"
                  }, 100, "linear");


                $( ".appearLate" ).animate({
                    top: [ "-1", "swing" ],
                    opacity: "1"
                  }, 500, "linear");

}
```

The script works great - unless..  You scroll up and down fast - which triggers both scripts at once - which means things fade out and in again at the wrong time - is there any way I can stop the script from reacting like this - ie disabling a function whilst another is running?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop currently running animation

```
  $('.notificationArea .notif').stop().animate({
                opacity: 0
              }, 1500);
```

or

```
stop(true,true)
```

with true in arguments, rest of the animations in the queue are removed and never run.Usually `stop(true,true)` is used in such cases

Comment: that cool cheers bipen..  So in the case above I'd apply the stop to the notif toggle function only i guess?  Seems to do the trick on a quick test anyhow..

Comment: yes ... apply in befor animation call... so that it stops any animation current running.. :)... glad it help.. cheers